# Solve the equation $f(x)=\sum_{n=x}^{10}\sqrt[|n-2|+1]{n\log_{2}(n)}$ for $x$ in $f(x)=7.5?$

Tags: functions, summation, logarithms, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Given the following equation

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=x}^{10}\sqrt[|n-2|+1]{n\log_{2}(n)}$$

How could I go about solving for $x$ in $f(x)=7.5$ for example (or to show that no such $x$ exists)? Or, really for any value of $f(x)$?

---

Here's an image of the graph that this produces, via the [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

[image]

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your question. If $x$ isn't an integer how can you start a sum there? Can you tell us where this problem comes from? Are you sure you have stated it correctly? In any case you could begin by working out $f(10)$ and $f(9)$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Unfortunately I don't have much information on the equation. A friend told me about it, but they don't know where it comes from either. Just from looking at it, it appears that indeed $x$ would have to be an integer. As well, while checking for values for $x$ that are above or below the value I'm searching for is a great idea, I don't know how to apply it to solving for any such $x$ given the value of $f(x)$.

Comment: You won't be able to solve for $x$ in general. $x$ must be a positive integer. It might have to be no bigger than $10$ (not sure) so there's just a sequence of values of $f(x)$ 0- maybe only finitely many. It's unlikely that $7.5$ is one of them.